# Increase code font size in Texifier editor

Tags: fonts, editors

I want to know how to make the latex codes part larger in Texifier. I learnt that in overleaf you can always click menu and set font size. But I don't know how to do that for Texifier. Thanks

Comment: "CMD" + "+" should do. Look at [this doc link](https://www.texifier.com/docs/apps/workspace/menu-items) (I do not use Texifier).

Comment: Hi, welcome. I edited your title to make it more specific, hope that's OK. (There are after all lots of editors :) )

Comment: in my Mac cmd and + will enlarge the PDF viewer instead of latex half.